# dm-verity: development flag to allow changes

Tags: linux, security, openssl, signature

I have two partitions; on for the root file system and one for my application. I've set up dm-verity for the rootfs, but not for the appfs. Sometime I want to add something to the rootfs without regenerating and signing the root hash (i.e. with apt-get install xyz).

What I would like to create is a check in initrd that checks the signature if it has i.e. a "development flag" and if so it will mount the rootfs as EXT4. If the flag is not present it will mount through dm-verity.

Is there a possibility to add such a flag to a signature?